# Compare and copy the match column into the next column using macro

Tags: vba, excel, macros, excel-2010

I'm just new to macros and have stuck with a problem. Well I got a macro file on the web that compare the two sheets and copies the found match into the 1st row.

```
Sub test()
Dim rng2 As Range, c2 As Range, cfind As Range
Dim x, y
With Worksheets("sheet1")
    Set rng2 = Range(.Range("B2"), .Range("B2").End(xlDown))
    For Each c2 In rng2
        x = c2.Value
        With Worksheets("sheet2").Columns("b:B")
            On Error Resume Next
            Set cfind = .Cells.Find(what:=x, lookat:=xlWhole)
             If cfind Is Nothing Then GoTo line1
             y = cfind.Offset(0, -1).Value
        End With
        c2.Offset(0, -1) = y
line1:
    Next c2
End With

End Sub
```

However I didn't understand how is it exactly working? I mean I just want to reverse the existing logic. I mean I want to populate the found match in next row to the data in C column not in A.

I attempted modifying the Offset index values it didn't work. Can anyone please help me out solving this.

Thanks !

Comment: If you want to find out how exactly it's working, split the screen into 2 windows i.e. excel and VBA and run the VBA code in debug mode step-by-step (f8). What values did you set for offset index to copy the values to column C instead of A?

Comment: @Spidey Thats the part I'm unclear of. Actually the data after running the macro is populating in column A but I want it to happen in column C. I tried changing the offset to `(0,1)`,`(0,-2)` etc

Comment: Since you are new to macros, try first recording the macro and seeing what code is generated for which action, it will give you some insights on how to write VBA codes

Comment: I ll follow your recommendation. Thank you @Spidey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub test()
Dim rSh1 As Range, rSh2 As Range, rFound As Range, r As Range

With Worksheets("sheet1")
    Set rSh1 = .Range("B2", .Range("B2").End(xlDown))
End With

With Worksheets("sheet2")
    Set rSh2 = .Columns("b:B")
End With

For Each r In rSh1
    With r
        Set rFound = rSh2.Find(what:=.Value, lookat:=xlWhole)
        If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
            .Offset(0, 1) = rFound.Offset(0, -1).Value
        End If
    End With
Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: Initial Code revised.  So please check and confirm :)

Comment: Just one more help.. How can I modify this script to read data from another excel file and do the same. Here all the data are in one xls files only but different sheets.

Comment: Currently we mentioned sheet name only Worksheets("Sheet1").  Just add workbook name along with it Workbooks("Book1").Worksheets("Sheet1").  Replace Book1 to your actual workbook name.  Also note that it should be in open.

Comment: Thank You so much ! Really appreciate your help :)